# How to install python3 with all it is tools on Redhat RHEL7 offline machine

Tags: rhel, software-installation, package-management, python, pip

I have a Django project that is going to be installed in an RHEL 7 server with no internet access. I need to include everything locally, starting from python3 source, to pip and setup tools. with every package that the system may need to run python, I have added tons and tons of packages, but still, it gives me error all the time. I'm using this `install.sh` script to achieve that purpose

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd ./needed_pkgs/
rpm -i build-essentials-2019-3pclos2019.noarch.rpm zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64.rpm gcc-c++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm cpp-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-devel-2.17-292.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-headers-2.17-292.el7.x86_64.rpm kernel-headers-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64.rpm
command -v python3 >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
  echo >&2 "I require python3 but it's not installed, installing it .";
  cd Python-3.7.5
  make clean
./configure
make
sudo make install
}
cd ../..
#virtualenv --never-download venv
#source venv/bin/activate
for entry in "./pkgs"/*; do
  pip install "$entry"
done
```

After days of trying, and as I was getting close to getting it all working, I got this strange error at the last step of pip install :

[image]

[image]

And it ends up with a failure in installing python:

[image]

Comment: What is in the `pkgs` file? You are getting `pip: command not found` because the build failed and even if it had succeeded, you didn't add it or any of the binaries that you build to your environment so as far as your script is concerned, there is no `pip`.

Comment: Why aren’t you installing the packaged python3?  I guarantee you’ll need more dependency devel packages to be able to build python and the modules than you would just installing the packages.

Comment: @jsbillings Can't find a binary rpm or packed in python.org, will really appreciate it if you can tell me where to look for it.

Comment: RHEL comes with python3 packages. If you can’t install them normally, you need to sign into https://access.redhat.com and download them.

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the specific module binary available by yum and copy it to the offline server, so you are basically downloading a binary module on your machine followed by copying the directory into the designated place from your VPN.

one solution can be to use `yumdownloader --resolve <package name>`

The order of installing them is determined by yum:

`yum install ./*rpm`
Now you have to run above command in the folder with your downloaded packages that include all dependencies and it will do the needful.